# Can't edit tag wiki in main

Tags: bug, tag-wiki

If I go to https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/voting/info , I get a "Propose Tag Wiki" button, but if I go to https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-request/info , I don't get a button.

In both cases, the text is:

> There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!
>
> Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain an
>   overview of the topic defined by the tag, along with guidelines on its
>   usage.
>
> All registered users may propose new tag wikis.
>
> (Note that if you have less than 2000 reputation, your tag wiki will
>   be peer reviewed before it is published.)

As far as I know, I'm a registered user.

Comment: I can see the buttons on both main and meta (in IE8/Windows and Chrome/Mac - maybe try a different browser?) There is another way to get to the editing page that you can try: On the page that shows questions with a tag (for this tag, http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-request), click the *help us create it?* link.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either. I see the button in both the sites. I was suggesting there could be a pending suggested edit, but it is not the case.

Comment: I can see the buttons on both main and meta using Firefox 21.0/Windows, too. Which browser/OS did you use? Does this issue still occur?